# Check if the username is unique in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backend

Working with spring-boot ,I created a method in a rest controller so i can check if the username is unique or not.

The problem is i'm trying to call this method in ARC Client , but it seems like there somthing wrong with the code , all usernames i'm checking give as result :

```
{
"emailIsAvailable": true
}
```

While it should return in some cases : false as the username exists.

This is the rest Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/checkEmailUnique",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public EmailStatusCheckJson checkEmailUnique(@RequestBody final String username){

         System.out.println("username********"+username);
        final EmailStatusCheckJson returnValue = new EmailStatusCheckJson();


         AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(username);


         if(app!=null){
             System.out.println("exists");
             returnValue.setEmailIsAvailable(false);
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("doesnt exist ");
             returnValue.setEmailIsAvailable(true);

         }

         return returnValue;
    }
```

This is the way i'm sending the request in Arc

[image]

The println of username in controller returns for exemple:

```
{
  "username": "admin@gmail.com"
}
```

*UserRepo.java*

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<AppUser,Long>{

        public AppUser findByUsername(String username);

}
```

*This is EmailStatusCheckJson.java*

```
public class EmailStatusCheckJson {

    private Boolean emailIsAvailable;

    public Boolean getEmailIsAvailable()
    {
        return emailIsAvailable;
    }

    public void setEmailIsAvailable(final Boolean newValue)
    {
        emailIsAvailable = newValue ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where r u inserting the username?

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `userRepo` as well? Also, does your database/data source already contains the username you are trying?

Comment: Did you unit test the userRepo.findByUser() function with existing and non existing email addresses to make sure it is returning the right results? Also it would be good idea to sanity check the email address string to make sure it contains a valid email address and to make sure to protect against SQL injection attacks

Comment: @IndraneelBende i send the username from ARC client , then i check if it exits in database using :  userRepo.findByUsername(username);

Comment: No , when do you insert it. Can u post that code.

Comment: @Saheb i've added the userRepo code , also my database already contains the email : admin@gmail.com , it's the one i'm authenticated with .

Comment: @ARau : i've already did tested this , the problem is i always get 'emailavailable' even if the email already exists.so it should return false but i keep getting true

Comment: @IndraneelBende : inserting it where ? i'm sorry i can understand what do you mean by inserting it . i've added all the classes needed for cheking the username

Comment: When do insert the username in d database. Do u have a rest controller for that?

Comment: Indeed , i have a rest controller for that  , i have an object User that contains all the attributs , i use userRepo.save to save it , there is no problem with that , in phpmyadmin i can check as well  if this email exists , and i get all 'admin@gmail.com' 's information as well .

Comment: @dEs12ZER, Can you check if `AppUser` contains `@Id` annotated `long` field. Also, you can log or sys out the value of app after `AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(username);` to see if repository code is working fine.

Comment: You are doing `@ResponseBody String username` and you expect that to have the value of the username... That isn't what is happening, what it actually will hold is the whole JSON string. `@ResponseBody` is something you should use when you want to marshal an object to json (and vice versa). You will need to create a wrapper object which has a `username` property and use the value of that property to call your dao.

Comment: AppUser contains @Id annotated with long field , the value of app is always null after userRepo.findByUsername(username); that's why i get "emailIsAvailable": true

Comment: @M.Deinum I see , can you please explain to me how to create 'a wrapper object '? do you mean a class with username attribute ?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was always wondering why we should wrappe an object if i want to send only one value , isn't there any other method? becaus i do always create classes when i send only one value .

Comment: Use a `Map<String, String>` and retrieve the values you want. Also why send JSON then? Just send a regular POST with a parameter in those cases. There is nothing wrong with that. Because you can use JSON doesn't mean you have to use it for everything.

Comment: Can you give me an exemple? so i can mark your answer :)